# How to hibernate .net application to reduce launch time?

Tags: .net, performance, launch

At the moment due to using some thirdparty components (which uses strongly reflection) our application is taking about 3 minutes to load on slow machines for our client.

I was wondering if there's a way to 'hibernate' .net application so that when launching again the state from the previous launch would be directly copied to memory and made available to run...

Comment: 3 minutes to load because of reflection doesn't sound right. Have you profiled the app to find out where the performance bottlenecks are?

Comment: I recommend to refuse those thirdparty components and find alternative way to do things.

Comment: Nhibernate also used reflection. I am worry about 3min time.May the problem is different. If your third party components take about 3 minutes to load then you should go for different options.

Comment: Yes, we profiled this app and know specifically which bottlenecks are and they are in those components. Unfortunately we cannot resign from using this components since this would mean a complete rewriting of the entire project (impossible to do)

Comment: This should not be a Community Wiki. People deserve reputation points for providing valuable answers to a question like this.

Comment: @Pankaj: This is not an NHibernate question (although the question caught my attention for that reason as well).

Comment: ...and the fact that NHibernate takes a ridiculous amount of time to start up doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is due to third-party components and/or reflection sounds like guessing to me. You could be right, and you could be wrong. At any rate, you can probably fix it in your code. To find out what to do, do this:

Start it up under the IDE, and while it's being piggy, hit the Pause button. Then look at the call stack and see what it's doing. Repeat a few times. That is a quick and dirty way to "profile" and it will tell you exactly what the problems are, no guesswork required.